# how to dynamically print function names stored in dict values?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm really new to python and coding in general. This is a little project I'm working on to implement a modular input system of sorts for a game idea I have. Just to learn really. Any help would be appreciated even if its just with how to phrase what I'm looking for?

I would like to have the pages(eg: intro, menu, stats, etc) each with their own options assigned to a number value which automatically updates as you input the required number.

I cant quite wrap my head around what I've managed so far, spent quite a while on tutorials, books, posts and some apps trying to get this going but I feel stuck now. I've tried many different ways and this is the closest I've gotten to something like what I want to do.

```
class Displays():
    def __init__(self, name, heading, pageOptions):
        self.name = name
        self.heading = heading
        self.pageOptions = pageOptions

    def printPage(self):
        print('  *** ' + self.heading + ' ***  ')
        print(self.name)
        print(self.pageOptions)     #I would like to replace this with something like the line below                                  
        #print(self.pageOptions().__name__)     



    def pageInput(pageOptions):
        pInput = int(input('Num: '))
        while pInput in pageOptions:
            print(pageOptions[pInput]())
            print(pageOptions[pInput].__name__)
            return pInput
        else:
            print('Invalid')

class Intros(Displays):
    pass


def Hello():
    print('Working hello')

def Bye():
    print('Working Bye')

def Exit():
    print('Working Exit')
    exit()




intro1 = Intros('Start', 'Starting Screen', {1 : Hello, 2 : Bye, 3 : Exit})
intro2 = Intros('Second', 'Second screen', {1 : 'Hey', 2 : 'Boo', 3 : 'Leave'})
intro3 = Intros('Third', 'Third screen', {1 : 'Hi', 2 : 'Good-Bye', 3 : 'Go Away'})

gL = True
while gL:
    Displays.printPage(intro1)
    Displays.pageInput(intro1.pageOptions)
```

What I'm currently getting->

```
 *** Starting Screen ***  
Start
{1: <function Hello at 0x000002D771AEC1E0>, 2: <function Bye at 0x000002D774110730>, 3: <function Exit at 0x000002D7741107B8>}
Num: 1
Working hello
None
Hello
  *** Starting Screen ***  
Start
{1: <function Hello at 0x000002D771AEC1E0>, 2: <function Bye at 0x000002D774110730>, 3: <function Exit at 0x000002D7741107B8>}
Num: 3
Working Exit
>>> 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

      *** Starting Screen ***  
    Start
    {1: <function Hello at 0x000002603AC9C1E0>, 2: <function Bye at 0x000002603D2C0730>, 3: <function Exit at 0x000002603D2C07B8>}
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Zander/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/accs.py", line 50, in <module>
        Displays.printPage(intro1)
      File "C:/Users/Zander/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/accs.py", line 14, in printPage
        print(self.pageOptions().__name__)
    TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
    >>>
```

---

When user inputs 1-3 I'd like it to display the name, run the function and update the options that it switches to. So that I can create the story line and everything as I did with intro1.

Comment: What you are doing is a little weird but replace ```print(self.pageOptions().__name__)``` to ```for i in self.pageOptions.values(): print(i.__name__)```

Comment: I'd also recommend you read up on OOP a bit more.

Comment: omg... thank you so much Joshua! i got it working exactly the way i want thanks to you. working with def printPage(self):
        print('  *** ' + self.heading + ' ***  ')
        print(self.name)
        for i,j in self.pageOptions.items():
            print(str(i) + ') ' +j.__name__)

Comment: also, do you have any recommendations for reading up on OOP?

Comment: You can try https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One choice is to adjust page options structure to contain name information which can introduce your function more detailed and is flexible which is independent of function name, like the following code.

Also you should not call instance method with Class although you can in python.

```py
class Displays():
    def __init__(self, name, heading, pageOptions):
        self.name = name
        self.heading = heading
        self.pageOptions = pageOptions

    def printPage(self):
        print('  *** ' + self.heading + ' ***  ')
        print(self.name)
        for key in self.pageOptions:
            print(' ', key, self.pageOptions[key]['name'])

    def pageInput(self):
        pInput = int(input('Num: '))
        if pInput in self.pageOptions:
            print(self.pageOptions[pInput]['entry']())
        else:
            print('Invalid')


class Intros(Displays):
    pass


def Hello():
    print('Working hello')


def Bye():
    print('Working Bye')


def Exit():
    print('Working Exit')
    exit()


intro1 = Intros('Start', 'Starting Screen',
                {
                    1: {'name': 'Hello', 'entry': Hello},
                    2: {'name': 'Bye', 'entry': Bye},
                    3: {'name': 'Exit', 'entry': Exit}
                })

gL = True
while gL:
    intro1.printPage()
    intro1.pageInput()
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you can replace that line with a dictionary comprehension.

```py
        print({n: f.__name__ for n, f in self.pageOptions.items()})
```

A dictionary has a `items` method that will return an iterable. Each iteration of that iterable contains a `tuple` like `(<key>, <value>,)`. This can be used in a dictionary comprehension to construct a new `dict` with slightly modified content.

Comment: Creating a new dict, just to print it is a waste of memory.